# Convert and check a string representing page numbers

Tags: javascript

I need to check if a string - which represents a page number - is valid; otherwise the string should be adapted if possible.

A valid page number could be `12` or `33-40`.

So first of all I'm removing spaces to make `33 - 40` also valid. Also I'm replacing special dashes.

```
value = value.replace(/\u2013|\u2014/g, '-').replace(/\s+/g, '');
```

Something special is that input could be in the format `530-5`, which should be converted to `530-535`. `530-41` should get `530-541`. I don't know how to get this done.

Next I would do a test if there are only digits or dash. Maybe this is not the best way?!

```
value = /^[0-9\-]*$/.test(value) ? value : undefined;
```

**Examples**

```
342         // valid
0           // invalid
12-15       // valid
12-5        // gets 12-15
15-12       // invalid
115-20      // gets 115-120
115 -  20   // gets 115-120
-20         // invalid
```

Comment: [`String.prototype.replace(regex, function)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Using_an_inline_function_that_modifies_the_matched_characters)

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, was misspelling

Comment: What about something as ridiculous as `100-5-20`? Should that be rejected, or converted to `100-105`, `100-120`, `5-20` or something else entirely? Or even the case of `20-20`, should it be rejected or converted to `20`?

Comment: @DavidThomas 100-5-20 should be rejected. 20-20 should get 20.

Comment: This isn't going to be posted as an answer (unless the question is updated to also accept non-regex solutions), because I'm not really a fan of regular expressions, but the following seems to meet your needs, albeit excessively verbose, [demo 1, using `Array.prototype.map()`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cbw4uj33/2/) and [demo 2, using `Array.prototype.filter()`](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cbw4uj33/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// create function to return normalised pagination
function getPages(i){
    // match pattern to extract pages from valid strigs
    // http://regexper.com/#/^\s*(\d+)\s*(?:(?:\u2013|\u2014|-)\s*(\d+)\s*)?$/
    var m = i.match(/^\s*(\d+)\s*(?:(?:\u2013|\u2014|-)\s*(\d+)\s*)?$/);
    // if there is a match then validate, else return null immediately
    if(m !== null && parseInt(m[1])) {
        // get references to first and second page numbers
        var from = parseInt(m[1]),
            to = parseInt(m[2]);
        // if there is a from and to page and to is greater than from...
        if(to && to > from) return from + '-' + to;
        // if there is from and to page and to is order of magnitude less than from
        else if(to && m[2].length < m[1].length) return from + '-' + (m[1].substr(0, m[1].length - m[2].length) + to);
        // if there is only from
        else if(!to) return from + '';
        // finally, if nothing else matched, return null
        else return null
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

['342', '0', '12-15', '12-5', '15-12', '115-20', '115 -  20', '-20'].forEach(i => console.log(getPages(i)))
```

Explanation of regex...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Something special is that input could be in the format 530-5, which should be converted to 530-535. 530-41 should get 530-541. I don't know how to get this done.

Following function should work to deal with this issue:

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/i7LLRIKJItgnaB4Ghmqd?p=preview)

```
<script>
    function getValidRange(pgNo) {
        var pgNoS = pgNo.split('-');

        var len1 = pgNoS[0].toString().length;
        var len2 = pgNoS[1].toString().length;
        var multiplier = 1;

        var newPage = "";

        if (Number(len1) > Number(len2)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < len1 - len2; i++) {
                newPage = newPage + pgNoS[0].toString()[i] + "";
            }
            multiplier = Math.pow(10, pgNoS[1].toString().length);
            pgNoS[1] = newPage + pgNoS[1];
        }
        if (Number(pgNoS[1]) < Number(pgNoS[0])) {
            pgNoS[1] = Number(pgNoS[1]) + multiplier;
        }
        return pgNoS[0].toString() + '-' + pgNoS[1].toString();
    }

    document.write(getValidRange('12-5') + "<br>");
    document.write(getValidRange('530-41') + "<br>");
    document.write(getValidRange('530-28') + "<br>");
    document.write(getValidRange('536-5') + "<br>");
    document.write(getValidRange('5312328-5') + "<br>");
    document.write(getValidRange('5312328-345') + "<br>");
    document.write(getValidRange('5312328-1211') + "<br>");
</script>
```

**Output**

```
12-15
530-541
530-628
536-545
5312328-5312335
5312328-5312345
5312328-5321211
```

*P.S.: The code is not tested for extreme cases. Feel free to point out any bugs/errors and I'll fix them for you.*